# Auto size a jQuery UI dialog in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, autosize

How can I autosize a [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) dialog in Internet Explorer?

This code is OK in Firefox, but not in Internet Explorer.

```
$('#dialog2').dialog({
    autoResize: true,
    show: "clip",
    hide: "clip",
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    position: 'center',
    draggable: true,

    open: function (type, data) {
        $(this).parent().appendTo("form");

    },
    buttons: { "close": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); document.getElementById("<%=btnnew.ClientID%>").click(); } }
});
```

My HTML element is a DIV.

Comment: What version of jQuery and jQuery UI are you using?

Answer (score 5):

I'm having success with `width: 'auto'` sizing jQuery UI dialog using the following "patch" (for IE) :

```
(function($) {
var fixDialogAutoWidth = $.noop;
if ( $.browser.msie ) {
    fixDialogAutoWidth = function(content) {
        var dialog = $(content).parent('.ui-dialog');
        var width = dialog.innerWidth();
        if ( width ) dialog.css('width', width);
    }
}

var _init = $.ui.dialog.prototype._init;
$.ui.dialog.prototype._init = function() {
    // IE magick: (width: 'auto' not working correctly) :
    // http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4437
    if ( this.options.width == 'auto' ) {
        var open = this.options.open;
        this.options.open = function() {
            fixDialogAutoWidth(this);
            if ( open ) open.apply(this);
        }
    }
    // yet another bug options.hide: 'drop' does not work
    // in IE http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/5615
    if ( $.browser.msie && this.options.hide == 'drop' ) {
        this.options.hide = 'fold';
    }
    return _init.apply(this); // calls open() if autoOpen
};
})(jQuery);
```

Just load this code after jquery-ui.js has loaded ...

Note that according to the ticket http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4437 we shouldn't be using width: 'auto' but I just couldn't live without it ... :)

Comment: i tried. i did add this code after jQuery-ui.js but it does not work yet :(. IE8

Comment: i'm sorry it did not work for u - i would start by logging and checking the value of `dialog.innerWidth()` in `fixDialogAutoWidth` ...

Answer (score 0):

Please first add a `,` at the end of the following line

```
buttons: { "close": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); document.getElementById("<%=btnnew.ClientID%>").click(); } }
```

IE expects that all options be closed off via `,`

Let's see if that does the trick (its probably good to ask what version of IE is this failing on?)

Comment: any results based on my above recommendation?