# jQuery Ui Dialog width:auto Ie8

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

i have jQuery Ui dialog like below code :

```
$("#RoleProperty").dialog({
    autoResize: true,
    show: "Clip",
    hide: "Blind",
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    position: 'top',
    draggable: true,
    title: "مشخصات نقش",
    open: function (type, data) {
        $(this).parent().appendTo("form");

    },
    buttons: { "بستن": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); document.getElementById("<%=btnCancel.ClientID%>").click(); } }
});
```

but the property width:auto works incorrectly in IE8.
it works right in Firefox.
jQuery Ui version is 1.8.5
jQuery Version is 1.5

> -Additional Infromation. i am opening this DIalog Server Side (after ASP.NET
>   Postback)

Comment: I'm having the same issue with jquery UI v1.8.9 and jquery v1.4.4, and that has nothing to do with compatibility mode. I'm interested... following the question with attention. I'm also loading the dialog's content in ajax mode from the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not having an issue with IE Compatibility Mode. Do you see a broken page icon by the refresh button?

If so use something like the following in your :

Comment: What do you mean by 'If so use something like the following in your : ' ?

Answer (score 0):

There was an interesting answer here :

[Auto size a jQuery UI dialog in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265316/auto-size-jquery-ui-dialog-in-ie)